# Как убрать margin у body, который у Хрома задан по умолчанию?

Tags: html, css

Известно, что браузеры прописывают некоторые отступы и другие свойства по умолчанию. Хром прописывает body margin: 8px. Есть в сети различные готовые файлы для сброса настроек по умолчанию: reset, normalize. Но хочется самому сбросить эту настройку. Сейчас прописываю в CSS так:

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Но не перебивает, margin так и остаётся 8px. Как прописать так, чтобы этот отступ удалить?

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зелёную галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте написать:
`margin: 0 !important`

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал, всё равно не обнуляет(

Comment: У меня в firefox, chrome работает margin: 0; даже без !important, может вы забыли перезагрузить страницу?

Comment: Вы правы, всё работает!